# Why are my AWS RDS backups being retained longer than configured?

Tags: amazon-web-services, rds

I have configured RDS to retain backups (snapshots) for 1 day, but I always see 3 days worth of backups being retained.  Why?

[image]

Comment: did you set the retention period when the instance got first created? or did you modfify it

Comment: @alex067 I modified it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **Q: Why do I have more automated DB snapshots than the number of days
>   in the retention period for my DB instance?**
>
> It is normal to have 1 or 2 more automated DB snapshots than the
>   number of days in your retention period. One extra automated snapshot
>   is retained to ensure the ability to perform a point in time restore
>   to any time during the retention period. For example, if your backup
>   window is set to 1 day, you will require 2 automated snapshots to
>   support restores to any within previous 24 hours. You may also see an
>   additional automated snapshot as a new automated snapshot is always
>   created before the oldest automated snapshot is deleted.

https://aws.amazon.com/rds/faqs/

Answer (score 0):

I just learned it can be **far worse**, than this.

In my case were 11 (Sic!) backups retained while the retention was set to 1 day.....
[image]

This happened since the machine concerned was an Acceptance machine that is often running for a few hours a day only (elastic!). Unfortunately, the DB concerned was 800GB, which made these copies rather expensive!

Since then I learned that ***the 1 day retention period is actually a 24 hour retention where only the 'running' state hours are calculated***........

> [As stated in the documentation (follow link for details)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_WorkingWithAutomatedBackups.html#USER_WorkingWithAutomatedBackups.BackupRetention), Backups can be retained longer
> than the backup retention period if a database has been stopped. RDS
> doesn't include time spent in the stopped state when the backup
> retention window is calculated.