# AWS RDS automated backup not deleted

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I have a RDS instance with automated backup configured for 2 days. Now I can notice I have 4 backups while I except only two. If I change the configuration to zero-days, all backups are deleted. I don't undestand why is not deleting the backups older than 2 days.

[image]

Comment: Perhaps this answers your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59886428/why-are-my-aws-rds-backups-being-retained-longer-than-configured